# Trying to center Material UI <TextField> element in React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to center two `<TextArea>` elements using material ui and React.

They are all in the same `<div>` and have same className. I've tried using the `!important` designation in CSS. Nothing seems to work on the MUI elements. A traditional `<input>` does what I want the other two to do using the same CSS. How do I center the `<TextField>` elements?

**JSX**

```
<Container maxWidth="md">
<TextField
id="outlined-read-only-input"
label="Username"
/> 
<TextField
id="outlined-read-only-input"
label="Password"
/> 
</Container>
```

**CSS**

```
.login__input {
  display: block !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
  width: 300px !important;
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu0xa.png
```

Comment: In general, this is a bad practice to modify MUI components with css. Can you show your JSX for this? Also, which MUI version are you using?

Comment: Updated with JSX @hpertaia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Grid elements for positioning.

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/

```
<Grid container justifyContent="center" spacing={2}>
 <Grid item xs={10}>
  <TextField
   id="outlined-read-only-input"
   label="Username"
  /> 
 </Grid>
 <Grid item xs={10}>
  <TextField
   id="outlined-read-only-input"
   label="Password"
  /> 
 </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: wouldn't this put grid items in a row?

Comment: i had to change the grid item to md but otherwise worked. Is there a way to put extra space between these inputs and the buttons? Or, in flexbox terms, something like align-content: space-between?

Comment: @hpertaia If both items were`xs={6}`, they would be put in a row. Grid row has 12 cols. If two items don't fit into one col, the second item is put below, just like in a column. `x={10}` on the other hand not only puts these items in column order, it also gives them 1 col padding on both sides (since the items are centered). https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#how-it-works

Comment: @CodeMonkey There are properties like `spacing`, `rowSpacing`, and `colSpacing`. I used `spacing` in my example.  https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#spacing